# how to change default settings for the new user (Vtiger CRM)?

Tags: settings, default, vtiger

When creating new user in Vtiger CRM lot of predefined settings (time zone, currency, etc.) are wrong form specific company setup. But I was unable to find info how to change in settings, nor with script, without getting too deep into file structure.

Is it possible (and how)?

Comment: Can you explain your query bit more please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the default value during entity creation, you need to change the order of values by setting the first value you want.
In vTiger each picklist has the values store in a table for example vtiger_time_zone for time_zone.
If, for example, you want to set the time zone to "Europe/Amsterdam" you need to find the corresponding value of the key field time_zoneid through query

```
SELECT * FROM vtiger_time_zone where time_zone = "Europe/Amsterdam"
```

In my case the corresponding time_zoneid returned by the query is 44.

At this point, it is necessary to change the sort order of the new desidered default value by excuting the query

```
UPDATE `vtiger_time_zone` SET sortorderid` = '0' WHERE `vtiger_time_zone`.`time_zoneid` = 44;
```

Finally, it is necessary that to move to the second position the option with time_zone = "Pacific/Midway" (time_zoneid = 1) by executing query

```
UPDATE `vtiger_time_zone` SET sortorderid` = '1' WHERE `vtiger_time_zone`.`time_zoneid` = 1;
```

Thew default currency value, instead, is given by the default value stored in $currency_name in config.inc.php and setted during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can change the Time Zone, Currency details from CRM GUI only without going into code**. Just follow this simple steps.

Login to CRM with any user. After login you will see User Name or Image (If profile picture set) on top right corner. There you will get a link for "**My Preference**". Click on that link which will allow to change User wise Setting. This setting will be User wise so it will not take effect for other Users.

Cheers!!!!